# Twisted web problem when serving docx files

Tags: python, docx, twisted.web, twistd

I have a question for you!

I'm running a simple webserver with **twistd web** and it works great must of the time. I have a problem serving **.docx** files.

Let me explain with an example.
On my webserver I have two files: *file.pdf* and *file.docx* (the x is important).

Now, on my browser, if I enter the URL of the pdf file, the browser will start the download (or open it depending on user preferences). This is the expected behavior.
But if I enter a link to a docx, instead of downloading it, the browser will display it as a sequence of strange letters and numbers.

It is not a browser issue, because if a click on a docx file served from another webserver, the browser will download it.

I'm starting the webserver directly from the windows cmd prompt using `twistd`. The line looks like this:

```
twistd -no web --path d:\shares\
```

The question is: how can I tell twistd to force the download of docx file the same way it does for pdf?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you shared some of your code, but I think the basic idea is that you should add the correct [MIME type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types)  to the header that your server returns, which will help the browser know what to do with it rather than try to render it as text. Based on the docs [here](https://docs.twisted.org/en/twisted-18.7.0/web/howto/using-twistedweb.html#modifying-file-resources) it looks like you want something like this:

```
from twisted.web import static

root = static.File("/files")
root.contentTypes[".docx"] = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
```

Using the somewhat long-winded MIME type for docx.

Comment: thanks for your help, actually I cannot share any code because I'm just starting twistd (the demon tool) from the command line with just a few arguments. I add the command line to my original question.

Comment: can I add this content type definition from the command line as well?

Comment: OK, as far as I understand you need a plugin to do this and can't do it from the command line. But also I tried to reproduce your situation, and opening the link to a `docx` file correctly triggers a download, without any configuration. Opening the root page shows each file in the directory and its MIME type, and the `docx` shows the correct type. Maybe this is an issue on the browser or OS level?